# KDevelop building plugin problems with undefined reference

Tags: qt, qt4, kde-plasma, kdevelop

I'm getting undefined reference to KDevelop::IPlugins. I know this means i'm missing the libary but I'm not sure which library this is. Where would I find this .so that I am missing?

Comment: A little more detail is required. What exactly is it you are trying to do and what are the error messages?

Comment: I'm trying to run make on this source code. I'm getting an undefined reference my main question is where are the libraries for building a plugin in for KDevelop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KDevelop::IPlugin is defined in libkdevplatforminterfaces.so ("kdevplatforminterfaces" to cmake).